# Keyboard shortcut for closing the current IE 8 window?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer

What's the shortcut for closing the current tab or window? Also, the new Win 7 shortcuts don't work for me.  For instance Alt + Space + X maximizies  the window but Win + UpArrow doesn't work.  Weird.

Comment: What model of computer do you have, and is it a laptop?  Laptops come loaded with so much bloatware, one of the preinstalled programs could be filtering your keyboard.  I had this problem on an Asus laptop.

Comment: Business HP desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the current tab.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the current window.

Comment: ALT+F4 has only been around since Windows 3.11 LOL

Comment: Ctrl+F4 also closes the current tab.